# Leray-Hirsch principle for étale cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, etale-cohomology

Let $p:E\to B$ be a continuous map of topological spaces and set $F_x=p^{-1}(x)$ for an $x\in B$. Take a commutative ring  $A$ and assume for simplicity that each $H^\*(F_x,A)$ is a free $A$-module. Let $a_1,a_2,\ldots \in H^\*(E,A)$ be classes that give a basis of $H^\*(F_x,A)$ when restricted to any $F_x$. Assume that the direct image $R^0p_\ast \underline{A}_E$ of the constant sheaf on $E$ is constant. The Leray-Hirsch principle says that $H^\*(E,A)$ is a free $H^\*(B,A)$-module generated by the $a_i$'s.

I would like to ask if anyone knows a reference for a similar result for étale cohomology. Ideally I would like to have a statement for $E,B$ varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$ and finite coefficients of order prime to $char (k)$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[[ I have added a discussion of when $p$ is smooth or has quotient singularities. ]]
[[ I added a discussion on the cohomology of $[X/G]$. ]]

The étale case follows in a way that is altogether analogous to the topological
case. Let me give a proof that gives a teeny bit of extra information. I assume
that $\alpha_i$ is homogenous (with respect to cohomological degree) of degree
$d_i$. Then $\alpha_i$ gives a map in the derived category $A[-d_i]\to
Rp_\ast A$ and combining them a map $\bigoplus_iA[-d_i]\to Rp_\ast A$. If we can
show that this map is an isomorphism then we get an isomorphism
$\bigoplus_iR\Gamma(B,A)[-d_i]\to R\Gamma(E,A)$ which on taking
cohomology gives the L-H theorem. That this is an isomorphism can be checked
fibrewise and if the natural map $(R^ip_\ast A)_x\to H^i(F_x,A)$ is an isomorphism for
all geometric points $x$ we are through.

This condition is true under one of the following conditions:

- $p$ is proper (by the proper base change theorem).

  $p$ is locally trivial by the Künneth formula.

  The second case covers the case of a $G$-torsor. If $G$ acts on $X$ with
  finite stabiliser scheme (a condition slightly stronger than having finite
  stabilisers but which guarantees that $X/G$ exists) and the orders of the
  stabilisers are invertible in the ring of coefficients it is still true. This
  can be seen by looking at the stack quotient $X\to[X/G]$ which is a
  $G$-torsor (though with base a stack) and at $[X/G]\to X/G$ which induces an
  isomorphism in cohomology fulfilling the condition. It should also be possible
  to do directly imitating Deligne's proof (in SGA 4 1/2 I think) that the
  cohomology of $G$ is indendent of the characteristic (it use the sequence of
  fibrations $G\to G/U\to G/B$ where $B$ is a Borel subgroup and $U$ its unipotent radical).


  **Addendum**: Here are, as requested below by algori, some details on the fact that $\pi\colon[X/G]\to X/G$ induces an isomorphism for coefficients $A$ for which the order of the (group of connected components of the) stabilisers are invertible. (This of course is well-known, so well-known in fact that I don't know if there is a proper reference for it.) I will not use that the stack is a global quotient so we may as well consider $\pi\colon\mathcal X\to X$ where $\mathcal X$ is a stack with finite stabiliser scheme and $X$ is its spatial quotient. For simplicity I will assume that the automorphism groups are reduced (i.e., that $\mathcal X$ is a Deligne-Mumford stack). The general case can be proved along the same lines but would be longer and more technical. What we are going to show is that $R\pi_*A=A$. As the construction of the spatial quotient commutes with étale localisation on $X$ we may assume that $X$ is local strictly Henselian and then by the local structure theory of DM-stacks (to be found for instance in Laumon-Moret-Bailly) $\mathcal X$ has the form $[Y/G]$, where $G$ is a finite group which can be assumed to be the stabiliser of a point of $Y$ and hence has order invertible in $A$ and $Y$ is also local strictly Henselian. Now using the usual simplicial resolution $T_n=G^n\times Y$ of $[Y/G]$ we get that $H^*([Y/G],A)=H^*(G,A)=A$ as $H^*(T_n,A)=A^G$.

  $p$ is smooth. This is proved as follows: For any $A$-complex $K$ on $B$ we
  get a map $\bigoplus_iK[-d_i]\to Rp_\ast p^\ast K$ which we want to show is an
  isomorphism. This map is functorial so in particular if is an isomorphism for
  two complexes in a distinguished triangle it is so for the third. By Noetherian
  induction (assuming for simplicity $B$ is Noetherian) we may assume that $B$ is
  local Henselian and that the statement is true for $B$ replaced by the
  complement $U$ of the closed point. We start by showing that that implies that
  if $K$ is an $A$-complex on $U$ and if $j\colon U\to B$ is the inclusion, then the
  result is true for $Rj_\ast K$. Indeed, this follows directly from smooth base
  change which implies that $p^\ast Rj_\ast K=Rj'_\ast p^\ast K$, where $j'\colon p^{-1}U\to E$ is the
  inclusion, and then the result follows from the induction hypothesis. On the
  other hand, if $K$ is supported on the closed point $x$ of $B$, then the map is
  $\bigoplus_iK_x[-d_i]\to R\Gamma(E_x,K_x)$ which is an isomorphism as it is for
  $K=A$. Now, the mapping cone of $K\to Rj_\ast j^\ast K$ has support at $x$ so the statement
  follows.

  The only thing that is used about a smooth map is that $p$ is universally
  locally acyclic for the torsion primes of $A$ (SGA IV: Exp. XVI,
  Thm. 1.1). Unless I am mistaken this is true for $p$ that locally are of the
  form $E\times_GU\to B\times_GU$, where $E\to B$ is a smooth $G$-map, $U$ a $G$-scheme and $|G|$
  is invertible in $A$.

Another way of dealing with the $(G,X)$ case which I think should be more
efficient and general is, following Deligne, to split $X \to X/G$ up into $X\to
X\times_GG/U\to X\times_GG/B\to X/G$ (where $U$ is the unipotent radical of a Borel subgroup
$B$). Then $X\times_GG/B\to X/G$ is proper and in fact the Leray-Hirsch argument
applies provided a large enough integer is invertible in the coefficients (it is
in general not enough to invert the $|H|$ but one also needs to invert some
primes intrinsincally defined by $G$) and $X\to X\times_GG/U$ has more or less affine
spaces as fibres and induces an isomorphism if the $|H|$ are invertible. Finally
$X\times_GG/U\to X\times_GG/B$ is essentially a torus bundle and the cohomology of $X\times_GG/U$
can be analysed in terms of the cohomology of $X\times_GG/B$ and the characteristic
classes of the bundle.

Comment: Thanks, Thorsten! A couple of remarks: 1. How exactly does one show in the etale case that the derived direct image decomposes as a direct sum of shifted constant sheaves? 2. I really would like to avoid assuming $p$ a fibration in the \'etale topology.

Comment: 1. This is what my argument was supposed to show, I can expand if you point out what part is unclear to you. 2. As I said if $p$ is proper you are always OK otherwise I might be a little bit tricky however there are quite a few situations when it is still OK. On the other hand most of the classical cases where one applies LH have algebraic analogues which are fibrations in the étale topology so I would need more specificity to say more.

Comment: Torsten -- an typical example would be a smooth affine variety on which a reductive group acts with finite stabilizers. Then the geometric quotient exists and we can then consider the map into the quotient. As far as I understand this is not a fibration (or is it?) In any case the map is not proper. However in some cases one can construct the "Leray-Hirsch" cohomology classes.

Comment: OK, I've added a section which should cover that case.

Comment: Dear Torsten, I was wondering if you might help me understand your comment about the fibers of p_*A when p is smooth, since I'm having trouble picturing what you're saying.  To my eye, your claim implies that the pushforwards of the constant sheaf along A^2 --> A^1 and A^2 \ 0 --> A^1 will agree, which doesn't square.  What am I missing?

Comment: Torsten, thanks again! Re your second proposal: how does one compute the cohomology of a torus quotient? This can be quite tricky even in the complex case. All in all it seems that the stacky way would be the less painful one. Is there a reference where this (or any of the other possible approaches you describe) has already been implemented? But still, somehow I believe that this has nothing to do with group actions and that there is a statement similar to the one in the topological case.

Comment: @Dustin: I was a little bit hasty in the smooth case and have made a retraction. Note however that your case of `$\mathbb A^2\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb A^1$` does not fulfil the LH-condition. I still have some hope that given LH condition things would be OK. For the case of a torus quotient I agree that in general it can be tricky but given the LH condition I think it should be easier. @algori: I am not sure what you mean by a "statement similar to the topological case". 

Comment: (cont'd) If one uses the condition that I  use in my present version, i.e., that the fibre of the direct images are the cohomology of the fibres, then I don't know of any topological version of the LH result that is not covered.

Comment: Dear Torsten -- I  have a question regarding the "stacky" procedure: how does one prove that the map from the stack quotient to the quotient induces a cohomology isomorphism? Basically, this boils down to proving the Leray-Hirsch theorem, but this time one can assume that all geometric fibers are acyclic say with $\mathbf{Q}_l$ coefficients, but I'm not sure what exactly this implies since the map is not proper.

Comment: Dear Algori, note that I have answered your last question in a revision (though not exactly in the way you suggested but rather by proving directly the stacky statement).